# Parameter choice Supersingular Isogeny DH

Tags: elliptic-curves, post-quantum-cryptography, key-generation, isogeny

In [“Towards quantum-resistant cryptosystems from supersingular elliptic curve isogenies” by DeFeo, Jao and Plut](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/506.pdf) (PDF), the public parameters are defined as:

1. Supersingular curve $E$, and
2. bases $P, Q$ generating the torsion subgroup $E[l]$ respectively for Alice and Bob.

The parameters for the key exchange generated by Alice would be:

- Random elements $m, n$.
- The isogeny with kernel $K := \langle[m]P + [n]P\rangle$.
- Some other stuff beyond this question…

**So the question is:**

Why does it not suffice to generate the torsion subgroup (respectively the isogeny, defined by kernel) with just one point $P$? Taken the subgroup $\langle P\rangle = E[x]$ i could also generate an isogeny. Also the final isogeny could be generated by Bob using only $\mathit{Alice}'$ resulting curve $E_{\mathit{Alice}}$ and the image of the the point $P_{\mathit{Alice}}$ as well as Bobs secret parameters.

Answer (score 3):

**Found the answer:**

The $l$-torsion subgroup is isomorphic to a direct sum of two quotient groups:
$E[l] \simeq \mathbb{Z}_n \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$, hence the basis requires two points and the elements of $E[l]$ are represented by linear combinations of such a basis.
[Reference: Elliptic Curves, Washington, section 3.1]

Comment: You should be able to accept your own answer once enough time has passed; see [here](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/).